# Best way to roundtrip a pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm generating some `pd.Series` with custom `index`, i.e. `x = pd.Series(index=some_array, values=other_array)`, that I'd like to persist to disk and load again as a `pd.Series` in another script.

Right now, I'm using `pd.Series.to_csv` and `pd.Series.from_csv`, but in the [documentation for `from_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Series.from_csv.html), it's mentioned that the function is deprecated and that `pd.read_csv` ought to be used instead.

However, `read_csv` does not seem to be able to load data from disk as a `pd.Series` when there is a custom `index`. What I'm doing now seems fine, but I'm wondering if there is a "common" way to roundtrip `Series` to and from disk.

Comment: Specify `squeeze=True` when you `read_csv`?

Comment: Thanks @ALollz but looking at the docs for `read_csv`, it indicates that only supports data with only one column, which would exclude a custom `index`

Comment: You should be able to `pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', squeeze=True, index_col=0)` which will get whatever your custom index is back into the index. That series will be named so you can add on a `.rename(None)` but probably just use `.pkl` if you can which is simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pickle the series using `pd.Series.to_pickle` and load it via `pd.read_pickle`. This is a much better option than going via csv as it actually preserves the object. It is also a lot faster.